dashboard in Colab
When I write the code
dashboard(xgboost, display_format='inline')

in Colab the error is
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-49b21d5f97d8> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 dashboard(xgboost, display_format='inline')

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pycaret/utils/_dependencies.py in _check_soft_dependencies(package, severity, extra, install_name)
    150         if severity == "error":
    151             logger.exception(f"{msg}")
--> 152             raise ModuleNotFoundError(msg)
    153         elif severity == "warning":
    154             logger.warning(f"{msg}")

ModuleNotFoundError: 
'explainerdashboard' is a soft dependency and not included in the pycaret installation. Please run: `pip install explainerdashboard` to install.
Alternately, you can install this by running `pip install pycaret[analysis]`

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

And yes I have installed all the libraries for this and even the ones he asked for pip install explainerdashboardand `pip install pycaret[analysis]'

Welcome to SO! Did you restart your kernel after installing the modules?
